# Excel - Need to search list cell for substring from array, can't get index/match to work?

Tags: excel-formula

As described, I'm trying to search individual cells for a substring that matches an array of values, and for some reason none of my usual tricks are working.

More specifically, I have a list of descriptions in a column.  Some of those descriptions include airport codes.  In a separate sheet I have a list of 35,000 airport codes.  What I want to do is search the each of the descriptions (separately) for a match against the array of airport codes and, if one exists, return the matching value.

I've typically used Index/Match, but for some reason it keeps coming up N/A.

Thanks,
Rick

Answer (score 0):

I found the formula... I knew I had it around somewhere.  In the event anyone else wants it:

`=INDEX(reference!$G$2:$G$39172,MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND(reference!$G$2:$G$39172,SageReportData1!$Q3)),-1,1)*(ROW(reference!$G$2:$G$39172)-ROW($G$2)+1)))`

That'll search the sub-string for an array of values and return the result.